# State counting machine with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm practicing with Pandas, Lambda functions, and facing a difficult task. I have already got a "formally" correct solution but absolutely inefficient.

This is the problem:

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df` which is something like this (the code to generate a sample of this at the end of this post):

```
     id  type
0  1003     G
1  1003     A
2  1002     T
3  1002     A
4  1001     A
5  1003     A
6  1002     G
7  1003     A
8  1001     T
9  1001     A
```

Expected output: a new column per each different type (A, C, G, T) which contains the number of unique ids which, in the last row they showed up in the table, have that type.

A possible output is this (edited to match the desired outcome):

```
     id  num_A  num_C  num_G  num_T type
0  1003      0      0      1      0    G
1  1003      1      0      0      0    A
2  1002      1      0      0      1    T
3  1002      2      0      0      0    A
4  1001      3      0      0      0    A
5  1003      3      0      0      0    A
6  1002      2      0      1      0    G
7  1003      2      0      1      0    A
8  1001      1      0      1      1    T
9  1001      2      0      1      0    A
```

To reach this goal, I have done the following (**which is not working properly if your compare the output with the table showed above**):

1. Defined a temporary DataFrame `tmp` which is storing the status of all possible ids (in this example there are a a maximum of 9):

   ```
    id  type_A  type_C  type_G  type_T


   0  1001       0       0       0       0
   1  1002       0       0       0       0
   2  1003       0       0       0       0
   3  1004       0       0       0       0
   4  1005       0       0       0       0
   5  1006       0       0       0       0
   6  1007       0       0       0       0
   7  1008       0       0       0       0
   8  1009       0       0       0       0
   ```
2. Defined an iterative loop which is checking which is the type of each row in `df` and then is updating accordingly the status of the `tmp` DataFrame:

Here's the code:

```
for df_row in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df.type[df_row] == 'A':
        for tmp_row in range(0, tmp.shape[0]):
            if tmp.id[tmp_row] == df.id[df_row]:
                tmp.type_A[tmp_row] = 1
        df.num_A[df_row] = tmp.type_A.sum()
    if df.type[df_row] == 'C':
        for tmp_row in range(0, tmp.shape[0]):
            if tmp.id[tmp_row] == df.id[df_row]:
                tmp.type_C[tmp_row] = 1
        df.num_C[df_row] = tmp.type_C.sum()
    if df.type[df_row] == 'G':
        for tmp_row in range(0, tmp.shape[0]):
            if tmp.id[tmp_row] == df.id[df_row]:
                tmp.type_G[tmp_row] = 1
        df.num_G[df_row] = tmp.type_G.sum()
    if df.type[df_row] == 'T':
        for tmp_row in range(0, tmp.shape[0]):
            if tmp.id[tmp_row] == df.id[df_row]:
                tmp.type_T[tmp_row] = 1
        df.num_T[df_row] = tmp.type_T.sum()
```

What I would like to understand, is if using Lambda functions or a different approach is it possible to get a quicker result which is also better in terms of performances.

To generate a sample DataFrame like mine, you can use the following code (suggestions about how to tweak this are also welcome so I can learn more):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.randint(1001, 1004, size=10), \
                   'type_tmp': np.random.randint(1, 4, size=10), \
                   'type': '', \
                   'num_G': 0, 'num_A': 0, 'num_T': 0, 'num_C': 0})
for r in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    if df.type_tmp[r] == 1:
        df.type[r] = 'G'
    if df.type_tmp[r] == 2:
        df.type[r] = 'A'
    if df.type_tmp[r] == 3:
        df.type[r] = 'T'
    if df.type_tmp[r] == 4:
        df.type[r] = 'C'
df = df.drop(columns='type_tmp')
```

The temporary DataFrame is defined as follows:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(1001, 1010), 'type_A': 0, 'type_C': 0, 'type_G': 0, 'type_T': 0})
```

Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Why is there a 1 in column `num_A` on index row 2 for id = 1002 when the original data has 'T'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the revised version of the question, which is quite different from the original one, we can simply pivot and forward fill to get the state at any row, and then use value_counts to get the numbers:

```
state = df.reset_index().pivot(index="index", columns="id").ffill()
counts = state.apply(pd.value_counts, axis=1).reindex(["A", "C", "G", "T"], axis=1)
counts = counts.fillna(0).astype(int)
out = df.join(counts)
```

which gives me

```
In [193]: out
Out[193]: 
     id type  A  C  G  T
0  1003    G  0  0  1  0
1  1003    A  1  0  0  0
2  1002    T  1  0  0  1
3  1002    A  2  0  0  0
4  1001    A  3  0  0  0
5  1003    A  3  0  0  0
6  1002    G  2  0  1  0
7  1003    A  2  0  1  0
8  1001    T  1  0  1  1
9  1001    A  2  0  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you!!! For all your patience and support! BTW this thing improved my knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

To find the unique set of types from the dataframe so far, you could take a slice of the dataframe from the start to each row and then force it into a Set and take the length. If you already have your dataframe set up with the proper columns (all 0's) you can insert the length of the this set into the right place:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    l = len(set(df['type'].head(index)))
    t = row['type']
    df['num_'.format(t)][index] = t
```

Let me know if this helps, I can add more if you need.